# When do I REALLY need to pronounce an s as a z?

Tags: pronunciation, plural-forms, phonetics, third-person-singular

Yeah, I know the rule that after a voiced consonant, the plural or 3rd person S should be realized as a Z. But I wouldn't trust that rule as far as I could throw it, because I constantly hear, say, 'problemsss' instead of 'problemzzz', or 'comesss' instead of 'comezzz'. What is the right pronunciation?

Comment: Just to be clear - you hear other people saying "come*sss*" with a hissing sound instead of "come*zzz*" with a buzzing sound?  Are these people native speakers?

Comment: If you constantly hear things like *problemsss* and *comesss*, you're listening to non-native speakers (or native speakers parodying someone with a stereotypical German accent, for example). Check [this](http://www.elementalenglish.com/3-sounds-of-the-plural-s-in-english/) out: *Voiced sounds that cause the plural “s” to be pronounced as [**z**] include: [b], [d], [g], [l], [r], [w], [**m**], [n], [v], [y]*

Comment: @stangdon Apologies for my ambiguous explanation, yeah, you're right, I don't hear any buzzing sounds there. That topic actually reminded me of the popular folk song "She'll be coming around the mountain", and again, I hear an s there in the "comes". You can listen to it right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9eRTAK8qBE

Comment: @Rusty Be careful picking up pronunciation from songs -- singers do all sorts of crazy things to make their pronunciation sound more musical, things you wouldn't do in spoken English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid no, I heard that from native speakers. Besides that song, I also heard that in an old video game where an Italian American said, "..it'll just bring us moah problemsss". Maybe that's because he is an Italian? If you want, I might as well give you the link.

Comment: @Rusty Listen to this fellow sing it - he emphasizes the final 's' more. https://youtu.be/kktJdHG272c?t=18  .  On the other hand, I'm hearing a lot of singers on Youtube dropping the final 's' almost entirely, I think because the hissing ess is not such a pleasant singing tone.

Comment: @relaxing Yes indeed, it appears you're damn right.. And they say songs is the best way to learn a language. Thank you for your thoughts though!

Comment: @Rusty The differences you hear may well be down to differences in pronunciation between different dialects. I would also say that natives will (in general) not emphasise the s on the end of the word, so it (generally) won't sound so obviously like the z in buzzing. It will also (in general) sound different if you ask someone to say something like "dogs" and "dogz" because they will emphasise the "z" in "dogz".

Comment: If you go with the rule you will be pronouncing it right to most people most of the time.

Comment: In Brit spelling you'll see and 's' where American spelling of English has changed it for a 'z". Realise/realize and so on. There are many examples of 's' being pronounced as 'z'. It depends on where you live on how something is spelled or pronounced. I recommend using your browser. "Pronounce 'realise' in North American English/ British English will get you youtubes and pronunciation guides galore.[Here's one:](https://youtu.be/kNbVMVKdagI)

Comment: @SteveES That explains a lot, thank you! But what does "not emphasise" mean? Does that mean that I can simply turn a final s into an s sound or that it sounds something like in between? When I speak, I actually stick to the latter

Comment: @Rusty I guess it generally sounds somewhere in between s and z. Maybe you could think of it like a short z? As in, so short that the "voiced" aspect of it only just sounds.

Comment: @Rusty - Songs are good for helping you learn because they stick in your mind easily.  They're *not* good for learning from because they're usually written to sound good, not to be grammatically or phonologically correct.

Comment: This is a question about phonetics and it cannot be answered completely by a dictionary, which provide phonemic transcriptions and generally do not even mention phonetic phenomena like devoicing.  I've reopened the question.

Comment: @stangdon Native speakers won't generally produce a buzzing sound at the end of w word like *problems*, unless there is another voiced sound afterwards (so they will of they say *problems are*, for example). Even though your brain tells you that there's a /z/ at the end of the word, there will usually be no vocal fold vibration during that segment. Perhaps see my answer below :)

Comment: @SteveES That because there *won't* be any buzzing usually! See my answer below :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers If OP is hearing no buzzing it because there *is* no vocal fold vibration if the /z/ occurs before silence. Your brain is telling you its a /z/ because of the length of the preceding vowel! Perhaps see my answer below ...

Comment: @Araucaria: Am I missing something? So far as I'm aware, if there's no vocal fold vibration then ***by definition*** it's a /s/, not a /z/. Are you saying there's some other difference between the two phonemes?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes! See my answer post ...That's why phoneticians (an phonologists) have to use the terms *fortis* and *lenis* to describe phonemes like /s/ or /z/ instead of using the terms *unvoiced* and *voiced* - and why it's important to use the term *devoiced* as opposed o *voiceless*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Among many other differences, fortis consonants like /s/ involve more exertion in terms of expressing air from the lungs. They last longer than lenis consonants (see Javalette's post). Importantly, they have different effects on preceding vowels - which is how we differentiate them from lenis ones when they occur in sullable codas (the end bits of a syllable). The glottal setting for fortis and lenis consonants are also different. They aso interact with different phonologica rules differently. We we can drop a /d/ when it's followed by a consonant whether it has ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... vocal fold vibration or not. We cannot drop a /t/ when followed by a consonant uness the preceding consonant is fortis (i.e. notionally unvoiced). So we can drop the /d/ in *pained me*, whether the /d/ has vocal fold vibration or not. We cannot drop the /t/ in *paint me*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What makes you recognise a syllable final /s/ or /z/ is not the vocal fold vinration. It's the length of the preceding vowel (plus any nasals or approximants  - m, n, ŋ, r, l, w, j)

Comment: @Araucaria - All I'm saying is that if there's a sound at the end of *comes*, it's a voiced sound, not the sibilant *sss*.  There is distinctly a difference between the voiced and unvoiced s, and the unvoiced just sounds wrong, although in practice we don't exaggerate the difference.

Comment: @stangdon That's not what the science says. It's till a /z/, but it won't be voiced if there is no following voiced sound. See my post for more info.

Answer (score 10):

We do indeed need to pronounce plural, 3rd person and possessive S as described in the Original Posters question. In other words it is realised as an /s/ after unvoiced consonants, and as a /z/ in other situations (after vowels or after voiced consonants).

**However!** When a /z/ occurs before silence or before an unvoiced consonant (i.e. when it doesn't have a voiced sound afterwards), it will become partially or fully devoiced. In other words, the vocal folds (sometimes called *vocal cords)* will stop vibrating.

This means that a /z/ which occurs at the end of word, before silence—or a /z/ which occurs before an unvoiced consonant—will sound a lot like an [s]. So if you listen very carefully to the /z/ at the end of the word *problems*, it will have a very [s]-like quality. Notice though that this does NOT mean that the /z/ has become an /s/!!!

Why not? Well, there are other differences between /z/ and /s/ apart from voicing. Some of these are quite complicated (so, for example, less force is needed for the production of /z/. We see a very high intraoral pressure for /s/, which we don't see for /z/.) The most important difference is *prefortis clipping*.

**Prefortis clipping**

Consonants which are usually unvoiced are called *fortis* consonants. When fortis consonants occur at the end of a syllable, they have a strange effect on the preceding vowels (and any following voiced consonants) in that syllable. So, for example, if you listen to the vowels in the words *peas* /pi:z/ and *peace* /pi:s/, you will be able to hear that the vowel in *peace* is only half as long as the vowel in *peas*. It is the length of a vowel in a syllable that tells a native English-speaker that the consonant at the end of the syllable is fortis (i.e. normally unvoiced), or lenis (normally voiced).

Native speakers do not hear the actual voicing in consonants when they occur at the ends of words. The preceding vowel tells them whether that sound is a 'voiced' or 'unvoiced' sound. In other words, when a listener hears the long vowel in the word *peas* their brain tells them that the sound at the end is a /z/. If they hear a short vowel, their brain tells them that the sound at the end is an /s/. In fact this effect is so strong that native speakers will tell you that they can hear the voicing in the /z/ even if we measure it with a machine and show that there is no voicing there. If we just play the sound at the end of the word speakers will confidently tell you that it is an /s/, when it is really a /z/! We can even record someone saying *peas* and cut out some of the vowel. When we play the same recording, but with some of the vowel missing, listeners will clearly hear the word *peace* instead of the word *peas*.

**Advice for learners**

For 3rd person, plural and possessive S, you need to use a /z/ when the original word ends in a voiced sound. It doesn't matter if the /z/ is fully voiced or not. *Don't think about it*! Everything will happen naturally if you just put a /z/ at the end of the word. However, you must not use an /s/. If you use an /s/ in the word *peas* for example, it will be heard as the word *peace* because you will cause the vowel in the word to be shortened. This will happen without you thinking about it (it happens across different languages). It's nice to have peace with your fish and chips, but peas are much tastier.

Comment: Any advice on the downvote? I can't improve my post without it!!

Comment: You can see the prefortis clipping in my docks/dogs spectrogram. There is a noticeably bigger gap before the /k/. it doesn't seem to happen with nasal consonants, as in problems/violence.

Comment: In the case of short vowels like /ɪ/, I'm not at all convinced  that there's enough length difference between /bɪt/ and /bɪd/ for that to be the factor we use to discriminate those two words.

Comment: @PeterShor  It may not be the main factor (which might for example be glottalisation or something else) but it's certainly a stronger cue than voicing (which may not, as discussed exists!). Gimson gives figures showing durations in csecs for accented monosyllables.. He shows short (lax) vowels to be roughly 70% longer when followed by  a lenis consonant (e.g. as in *bid*) than when followed by a fortis one (e.g. *bit*) giving average values of 17 csecs for the former and 10 for the latter. I suppose the thing to do would be to record a *bid*, cut some of the vowel out ...

Comment: @PeterShor ... and see what word listeners thought it was. (I'm sure it's been done!). Perhaps someone can enlighten us ....

Comment: @Araucaria: [This paper](http://klio.umcs.lublin.pl/~gonet/papers/11.%202006%20Vowel%20Clipping%20in%20English...%20.pdf) says the effect of shortening of vowels before voiceless consonants almost disappears for lax vowels in connected speech. So I don't think it's just the length that determines lenis/fortis for lax vowels. Maybe context plays a role.

Comment: @PeterShor Do you mean semantic/pragmatic context?

Comment: @PeterShor as opposed to phonetic/phonological? (I'm open to either)

Comment: @Araucaria: Both? (I actually meant semantic/pragmatic context, but I'm certainly open to either, as well.)

Answer (score 6):

The production of phonemes in English can vary considerably between initial, medial and final positions. In general, the final phoneme of a final word tends to be less strong, and the voicing tends to end well before the phoneme has ended.

A native English listener allows for this and considers a final consonant to be voiced even if only the very beginning of the phoneme is voiced.

Here is a spectrograph showing the words docks and dogs.

[image]

The voicing is the lowest red line on the spectrum. Note that, in docks, there is no voicing visible in the final /s/, whereas in dogs, it is definitely present at the beginning but fades out gradually and disappears about half way through. When played in isolation, the final /z/ sounds half way between a /s/ and a /z/.

Note also that voicing is not the only discriminator between /s/ and /z/:  the /s/ is slightly longer in duration than the /z/.

It is quite possible that you might perceive dogs as ending with a /s/, but to an English listener, the two words are very different and the final phoneme in dogs is definitely a /z/.

This is what problems and violence look like: I chose the latter because it has a nasal consonant before the /s/.

[image: problems violence]

Note that the voicing is only present in the first (transitional) part of the /z/ in problems, and is completely absent in the /s/ of violence. Note also that the /s/ is considerably longer than the /z/. if your are not accustomed to listening to English, you might miss the release of the /m/ which is the boundary between the two phonemes, and mis-hear the final, sibilant part of the /z/ as a /s/.

Part of the process of learning a language is re-programming the ears to recognize each of the variants of each of the phonemes. When you are speaking the language, you should definitely stick to the rule that a final s is pronunced /z/ after a vowel or a voiced consonant.

Answer (score 4):

In many dialects of English, an epenthetic consonant is added between a nasal consonant /m/ or /n/ and a following /s/ (as long as they're in the same syllable).

That means that *prince* sounds exactly like *prints* and *Amsterdam* sounds like *Ampsterdam*.

So if somebody pronounces *sins* more like /sɪns/ than /sɪnz/, there's no ambiguity with *since* (pronounced /sɪnts/).  I believe the pronunciation has tended to drift towards /sɪns/ in some dialects, although I suspect it's often somewhere between an /s/ and a /z/. Native speakers hear /sɪnz/ because there's no /t/ in it.

You can't pronounce the plural 's' like /s/ after an /r/ or an /l/, because then you couldn't tell the difference between *cores* and *coarse*, or *falls* and *false*.

So my answer is

- if people pronounce a plural 's' following an /m/ or /n/ closer to an /s/ than a /z/, they will still be understood.
- Not all native speakers do this, and if you're learning English you should just stick with pronouncing a /z/ after /m/ and /n/ in words like *problems, comes,* and *sins*.

Comment: I expect they're different for you, but in my non-rhotic world, *The **cores** must be investigated* is indistinguishable from *The **cause** must be investigated*. And my experience of the ***prints/prince*** distinction is that even if some people can and do pronounce them differently (a point I must remain open-minded about), I personally have never been able to actually *hear* the difference unless it's so exaggerated as to be completely non-natural. What I'm getting at is that *sometimes* the "minimal pair" argument doesn't completely dictate which articulations are or aren't possible.

Comment: Yes ... *falls/false* would probably have been a better example (although it's probably still true that /l/ turns into a vowel in these words in some dialects).

Comment: I don't understand how this response gets the most votes when it's the only one to get the answer totally wrong. The prince-prints merger results in the insertion of an (epenthetic) 't' sound, not a shift to 'z'. And this isn't relevant to the original question about when to shift from 's' to 'z', no epenthesis. (No says "problemts" or "come-ts".) Your advice about keeping the "ms" sound is terrible. It immediately marks the speaker as non-native, as others have already noted.

Comment: @relaxing: I don't think you understood what I wrote. While I say that some native speakers might have consonants closer to /ms/ than /mz/ in *problems* (which explains what the OP is hearing) I recommend that English language learners pronounce *problems* with /mz/ and ***not*** /ms/.

Comment: I was just listening to a (Canadian?) guy talking about [Black Holes in Globular Clusters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7bYOfl6iy0) last night. He frequently adds an extraneous schwa to the last word in any "utterance / sentence" (so his *problems* sound like *problem-zuh*), Perhaps it also made a difference that I was listening with a 25% speed increase, but when that last word ended in either **/s/** or **/z/** it often sounded to me as if he was interjecting **...so...** as a "filler", even though I knew that wasn't *really* what was going on.

Comment: If there's an epenthetic t that will of course give the game away. But the real reason that native speakers know whether a sound at the end of a word is an /s/ or a /z/, for example, is because of the length of the preceding vowel (see my answer).

Comment: You forgot a following /ŋ/ in your list of nasals. Like the word *angkst*, for example :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Stateside *cores* has the close GOAT vowel of *toes* just like when you say the name of the letter O itself, whereas *cause* has the lax THOUGHT vowel of *saws*. That's why *roars* at least comes quite close to *rowers* — and can sometimes even equal it under the same scenarios that can make homophones of [*pace* Peter :-] *shores/show-ers, lores/lowers, stores/stow-ers, sears/seers, hires/highers, dire/dyer, lairs/layers, mares/mayors* and all the rest of the pairs that can **sometimes** work out to sounding the same. But all pairs share the same vowel, no matter the syllables.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you turn the voiceless 's' into a voiced 'z' when it follows another voiced letter.  (This is known in linguistics as "progressive assimilation" -- the voicing of the first letter continues on into the second.)

Examples

- cats = 't' is an unvoiced consonant, so the 's' remains unvoiced
- dogs = 'g' is a voiced consonant, so the 's' turns into a voiced 'z'
- problems, comes = 'm' is a voiced consonant, so the 's' turns into a voiced 'z'

In case it's unclear, voiced means your vocal cords vibrate when you pronounce that letter (phoneme), whereas as voiceless letters are created with only a release of air. Voiced letters are (usually - there are always exceptions and special cases) b, d, th, v, l, r, z, j and all vowels.

Comment: You seem to have given examples of voiced letters, not voiceless ones...

Comment: No problem :) Your list is also not comprehensive (not sure if it's meant to be). You could (if you were feeling keen) also point out that "th" can be either (e.g. the or three).

Comment: @SteveES That's why I said "usually". There are plenty of exceptions and special cases and I'm not building a comprehensive list here. I'll add another note to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you might have to specify if you have troubles with the letter S at the end of words only or also in other positions, e. g. in the middle.

If the problem is about how to pronounce S at the end of the word, then there's no big deal. At the end of a word S can denote either a plural ending or a possessive case of a noun, or it can be the ending of 3rd person singular of Present Simple of a verb. It does not matter very much, because the rules for both noun and verb S-endings are the same. But I want to pay attention at the fact that it mostly depends on the preceding sound and not so much the letter.

So, here are the rules:

- S-endings are pronounced as [s] after a voiceless consonant sound. These are: [p], [f], [t], [θ], [k]. Examples: *caps*, *hoofs*, *hats*, *paths*, *rocks*.
- S-ending is pronounced as [z] in any of two essential cases:

  - **1)** after a voiced consonant sound. These are: [b], [m], [v], [d], [n], [l], [ɹ], [ð], [g], [ŋ]. Examples: *tubs*, *rooms*, *sleeves*, *beds*, *guns*, *rails*, *cars* (AmE), *mouths*, *logs*, *songs*.
  - **2)** after any vowel sound, including all monophthongs and all diphthongs. Examples: *trees*, *stars* (BrE), *cores* (BrE), *days*, *cows* etc.
- If you have ES-ending, which occurs only after sibilant consonant sounds ([s], [z], [ʃ], [ʒ], [tʃ] and [dʒ]), then you should know that this two-letter ending is pronounced always as [ɪz]. Examples: *cases*, *roses*, *wishes*, *peaches*, *pages* etc.
- Note also that the final S may be not an ending at all. It can be a part of the root. Examples: *bus*, *walrus* etc. In these cases it is usually [s].
- For the middle of the word, the general rule is that letter S denotes sound [s] between two vowel letters (vowel letter are: A, E, I, O, U, and Y). Examples include: *nose*, *these*, *raise*, *weasel*, *position*, *cosy* etc. But be aware because there is a bunch of exceptions. E. g. *base* and *research*, where we have [s]-sound and not [z].
- However, if a middle-word S is **not** situated between two vowel letters, then, of course, in absolute majority of cases it denotes voiceless [s]-sound. Examples: *purse*, *false* (not after a vowel); *nasty*, *biscuit* (not before a vowel); *holster* (between two consonants). Notable exception are S's before voiced plosives ([b], [d] and [g]), where S can denote [z]-sound. For example, we pronounce S as [z] in *husband*, *wisdom* or *disgust*. Also, S can be [z] in the suffix -ism of an abstract noun: *communism*, *capitalism* and so on.
- Finally, an S at the start of the word almost always is pronounced [s], disregarding of what follows it. E. g. *sun*, *see*, *sky*, *slow* etc. I think in English we never pronounce initial S as Z, because letter Z serves for that purpose: *zeal*, *zombie*, *zest* etc. One additional note: in a few words (very few), initial S is pronounced as [ʃ] (sh-sound) before a vowel letter. Examples of such words are *sugar* and *sure*.